# Grails tries to load zip file as plugin

Tags: maven, grails, zip, pom.xml, maven-dependency-plugin

I'm using Grails 2.1.1 with Maven. In my pom.xml I use **maven-dependency-plugin** that downloads some **common-java-script.zip** file from local maven repository and unpacks it into web-app.

That works fine, but then Grails fails with message:

```
|Packaging Grails application
Error |
Zip C:\Users\andreyk\.m2\repository\com\company\ui\common-java-script\1.3.0.0\common-java-script-1.3.0.0.zip is not a valid plugin
```

My understanding is that Grails interprets common-java-script-1.3.0.0.zip as its plugin and fails to load it. 
How do I tell Grails to ignore common-java-script-1.3.0.0.zip? Is there any better way to handle such situation?

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>pre-authorization</artifactId>
    <packaging>grails-app</packaging>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <name>pre-authorization</name>
    <description>pre-authorization</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com</groupId>
        <artifactId>company</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <grails.version>2.1.1</grails.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company.ui</groupId>
            <artifactId>common-java-script</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.0</version>
            <type>zip</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
            <artifactId>grails-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${grails.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
            <artifactId>grails-plugin-testing</artifactId>
            <version>${grails.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>${grails.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <type>zip</type>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>cache</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <type>zip</type>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <type>zip</type>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>resources</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.6</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <type>zip</type>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <type>zip</type>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>database-migration</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <type>zip</type>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>webxml</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <type>zip</type>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement />

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-owner</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.company.ui</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>common-java-script</artifactId>
                                    <version>1.3.0.0</version>
                                    <excludes>common/bootstrap.js</excludes>
                                    <type>zip</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                            <outputDirectory>web-app</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Disables the Maven surefire plugin for Grails applications, as we have our own test runner -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>surefire-it</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>false</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>plugins</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*</include>
                            </includes>
                            <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
                <artifactId>grails-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${grails.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Whether for Fork a JVM to run Grails commands -->
                    <fork>true</fork>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>grails</id>
            <name>grails</name>
            <url>http://repo.grails.org/grails/core</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>grails-plugins</id>
            <name>grails-plugins</name>
            <url>http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>tools</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>java.vendor</name>
                    <value>Sun Microsystems Inc.</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                    <version>${java.version}</version>
                    <scope>system</scope>
                    <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some stupid reason like end of day, lack of sugar etc I had an entry in my pom.xml that obviously caused a problem:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.company.ui</groupId>
    <artifactId>common-java-script</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.0</version>
    <type>zip</type>
</dependency>
```

After I removed it all worked out fine.